# Find error: Using Lualatex to print a table

Tags: luatex, luacode

I have 题 as a counter. I'm using LuaLaTeX and loaded the luacode package.

```
\newcommand{\scoretable}{
    \directlua{
        tex.print("\begin{tabular}{|c|")
        for i=1,\the题 do
        tex.print("c|") end
        tex.print("}\hline 题号")
        for i=1,\the题 do
        tex.print("&") tex.print(i) end
        tex.print("\\\hline\end{tabular}")
    }
}
```

Could anyone find the mistake? When I use this command `\scortable` it says it's not defined meaning that there's an error in the definition. Code above is in the .cls file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following modified version of your code works. :-)

The main change, really, is not to expand `\the题` inside the Lua code block. Instead, I suggest expanding the value of the counter first and then passing it to Lua. Also, note that `\` (backslash) is the generic "escape character" in Lua. Hence, one must write `\\` in Lua to generate a single `\` character for further prosessing by TeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}      % for "\extrarowheight" length parameter
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif SC} % or some other suitable font
\newcounter{题}

\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function scoretable ( n )
    local s 
    s = "\\begin{tabular}{|c|" 
    for i = 1 , n do 
       s = s .. "c|" 
    end
    s = s .. "} \\hline 题号" 
    for i = 1 , n do 
       s = s.."&"..i 
    end
    s = s .. "\\\\ \\hline \\end{tabular}"
    tex.sprint ( s )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX utility macro:
\newcommand\scoretable[1]{\directlua{scoretable(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % make the table look less cramped
\setcounter{题}{8}

\scoretable{\the题}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you wanted to stay closer to your original setup, I suggest you define the LaTeX macro called `\scoretable` via

```
\newcommand{\scoretable}[1]{
    \directlua{
```

```lua
        tex.sprint ( "\\begin{tabular}{|c|" )
        for i = 1,#1 do tex.sprint ( "c|" ) end
        tex.sprint ( "}\\hline 题号" )
        for i = 1,#1 do tex.sprint ( "&"..i ) end
        tex.sprint("\\\\ \\hline \\end{tabular}")
```

```tex
    }
}
```

and invoke it as follows: `\scoretable{\the题}`. Note the use of `\\` instead of `\`, as well as the fact the macro is defined to take an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You define `\scoretable` but you call `\scortable` which you haven't defined.

Comment: There's a deeper issue, beyond the typo in `\scortable`, with the OP's Lua code: It doesn't work at present, in part because the OP has failed to replace single-backslashes with double-backslashes.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typing mistake, I didn't type incorrectly in my document.